# How to achieve strumming effect while playing fingerstyle with bass notes, in a guitar?

Tags: guitar, technique

How to play upper strings to sound like strumming while keeping bass note?

```
    E|----6--
    B|---6---
    G|--6----
    D|-------
    A|-------
    E|--6----
```

Like quick strumming, there should be almost no delay between notes.

[Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6XQClS1ka6o)

Comment: Can you link to a sound file or a tube video, to make it more clear what you mean?

Comment: I would say the title is rather misleading -- I thought it was about bass guitar

Comment: I believe you want to play fast arpeggios. Does that soound right to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pluck the bass note with your thumb. Strum the remaining notes with back of the nails of your 1st, 2nd or 3rd finger.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to  Slim's technique, strum all strings but mute the A and D strings with the fretting hand. It is possible to mute these two strings for any particular fingering for the minor 7 voicing in question.